# How to Move switcher-btn with Ant Design Drawer in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

*I have a React component that includes a div (`switcher-btn`) and an Ant Design Drawer. I'm trying to move the `switcher-btn` along with the Ant Design Drawer when it's opened. Here's my code:
*

```
jsx
const BasicLayout: React.FC = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const showDrawer = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const onClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="switcher-wrapper">
                <div className="switcher-btn" onClick={showDrawer}>
                    <i className='ri-settings-2-fill bg-cog bx-spin'></i>
                </div>
                <div className="switcher-body">
                    <Drawer title="Basic Drawer" placement="right" onClose={onClose} open={open}>
                        <p>Drawer</p>
                    </Drawer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BasicLayout;
```

Here's my SCSS file:

```
.switcher-wrapper {
    width: 378px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: -378px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.switcher-btn {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background: #008cff;
    box-shadow: 0 .3rem .6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    right: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

*How can I move the switcher-btn along with the Ant Design Drawer when it's opened?

Thanks for your help!*

Answer (score 0):

For this you would have to track Drawer's open/closed status using this

```
const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
```

Next, update your **showDrawer** and **onClose** functions to set the drawerOpen state accordingly:

```
const showDrawer = () => {
  setDrawerOpen(true);
};

const onClose = () => {
  setDrawerOpen(false);
};
```

Now, you can use conditional CSS to move the "switcher-btn" when the Drawer is open. Like this

```
.switcher-btn {
  /* Other styles for the button */

  /* Move the button when the Drawer is open */
  transform: translateX(${drawerOpen ? "378px" : "0"});
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

With this CSS, the "switcher-btn" will move to the right when the Drawer is open and return to its original position when the Drawer is closed. The transition property ensures a smooth animation.